# Make File sensitivity on Preprocessor Definitions

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have written a make file.

In the make file i have used a variable, say EXTRAFLAGS which looks like this.

```
EXTRAFLAGS += -D _MSC_VER
EXTRAFLAGS += -D BINARYINPUT
EXTRAFLAGS += -D ENABLEVERSION2D2
```

Further,
I use Compiler flags

```
CFLAGS = -Werror -Wall -I $(INC) $(EXTRAFLAGS)
```

and

```
mingw32-gcc $(CFLAGS) -o nameofexe  OBJ's
```

I have used this makefile with out any problems. But when i disable the preprocessor definitions, by introducing '#' ahead of one of the statments in EXTRAFLAGS, and i remake it, i am getting target up to date. I am unable to introduce Preprocessor Definitions in to the sensitive list.

A temporary work around i am using currently is, introduce a phony target clean and remove all the object files and re compiling every thing. But this is a waste of time. How can i better manage the current scenario?

Comment: Do you mean that if you change `EXTRAFLAGS` the files are not re-built?

Comment: Yes, when i change extraflags, they are not re-built

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make is a tool that compiles your project new when one of your files in the project change.

E.g. when you change your .h file it recognizes the change and rebuilds all files that depend on it, and then rebuild all that depends on the new builds, ...

But when you change the compiler flags and/or the defines in the makefile the project input files do not change, so the project is not rebuild.

There are three ways to achieve what you want: First issue manually a make clean after changing the makefile. Secondly to include the makefile itself in your makefile (and issue there a make clean when it changed). And finally move the defines into some project specific .h file.

Generally only the "in-a-h-file-on-its-own"-solution is the only one, that avoids building everything new, as the others are not aware of which source files actually have a reference to the changed defines.

Comment: The first way is what i am doing currently. The third is what i don't want to do because i don't want the users to touch the source at all. Let the author of the source worry about it. I have added the name of my makefile to the sensitivity list along with my object files. This resolves the issue. Does the second way u stated is what i did or is it anything different?

Comment: @ram: yes that is exactly the second way.

Answer (score 4):

You have not made your .o file dependent on the Makefile within the makefile itself.

When you comment things in/out in the Makefile, you don't change anything which the .o file depends on -- unlike when you edit the .c file

You can fix this simply by creating a dependency of your .o or .c file to include the Makefile itself, and when you update anything in your Makefile all your source will recompile.

For example;

```
  SRC=a.c b.c
  OBJS=a.o b.o
  EXE=ab

  $(EXE): $(OBJS)
       gcc -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(...anything-else...)

  $(OBJS): $(SRC) Makefile
```

(*Now there are better ways of generating the .c and .o lists, but the above should suffice for this example*)

Comment: Yeah. This was exactly what i should have done. Introduce makefile in the sensitivity list along with the obj files. Thanks for the help.